# HtmlCanvas + globalAlpha + overlap = incorrect output color

Tags: javascript, canvas, opacity, alpha, overlapping

I want to draw a stack of almost transparent white rectangles that overlap each other.

Each rectangle has an opacity of 0.01

I have 100 rectangles overlaping, I expect the output result to be the sum of all the opacity. In other term, I expect the result to be white without any opacity.

But it's not the case.

1. Why ?
2. How to get the result I want ?

Here is a minimalist code to illustrate the problem

```
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 512;

let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,512,512);

ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.01;

for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
   let n = i*3;
   ctx.fillRect(n,n,512-n,512-n);
}

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Here is the result

[image: result]

And here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/hsqpno04/

Any help is very welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do alpha blending of two RGBA colors (assuming normal blending and  composite modes), the general formula is

```
out = alpha * new + (1 - alpha) * old
```

But `out` must be an integer (in the range 0~255), so we have to apply a rounding on top of that (I guess the rounding could depend on implementations and how they store color values).

If we take a less dramatic `alpha` of 0.1, and keep white so `new` is 255 (white is 255, 255, 255), and old is 0 (transparent),
at first step we'll have

```
out = round( 0.1 * 255 + (1 - 0.1) * 0 );
// => 26
```

following steps we'll have

```
out = round( 0.1 * 255 + (1 - 0.1) * 26 );
// => 49
out = round( 0.1 * 255 + (1 - 0.1) * 49 );
// => 70
out = round( 0.1 * 255 + (1 - 0.1) * 70 );
// => 89
[...] // a few iterations later
// => 250
out = round( 0.1 * 255 + (1 - 0.1) * 250 );
// => 251
out = round( 0.1 * 255 + (1 - 0.1) * 251 );
// => 251
out = round( 0.1 * 255 + (1 - 0.1) * 251 );
// => 251
```

Once you reach this `251, 251, 251` color value, no matter the number of new layer you'll add, it won't change the color value anymore, and thus you won't ever be able to reach a full opaque color by layering semi-opaque versions of that color if their opacity is less than 0.5.

Your `0.01` value will take more iterations to reach this stabilized position (153 vs 38), but it will achieve it at a lower value (206).

```
round( 0.01 * 255 + (1 - 0.01) * 206 )
// => 206
```

---

Note that colors are generally stored premultiplied by their alpha, which may add some rounding errors in these numbers.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. 
Yesterday I almost found a solution without any kind of logic, just by experimentation (but I prefer to understand what i'm doing, so thank you) 

The solution I found yesterday is here : https://jsfiddle.net/L25c649m/